# Jenkins with Git and XCode: cannot pull sub-sub-module?

Tags: ios, xcode, git, jenkins, git-submodules

I use Jenkins for CI, and git for XCode project, I have the XCode integration plugin and Git plugin installed, one of the submodules in my project has a sub-submodule, but Jenkins cannot pull it although it is said to be able to do that.

Does anyone have the same issue and any solution to this? I guess I have to add another execution step that pull all the sub-submodules?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have submodules and it seems to work well, but we had a project break on Thursday for reasons unknown, on a submodule so there must be some situations where the submodule makes it barf. If I find out more, I'll post it here.

Comment: For me, checking the Advanced Source Code Management option "Recursively update submodules" fixed things up.

Comment: Thanks, I tried that but it didn't seem to work. I think my issue is an authentication issue. I've seen others post about it but I'm unclear on how to fix it. Glad you figured it your problem out though